# Взаимодействие между страницами в разных окнах (C#, WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

Добрый день. Разбираюсь с WPF, столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

1. Есть главное окно с постраничной навигацией. На одной из страниц есть ListView (заполняется из БД) и кнопка "Добавить".
2. Нажимаем на кнопку "Добавить" - появляется дополнительное окно, где есть страница с полями ввода. Вводим данные, нажимаем "Сохранить" в этом окне и данные записываются в БД.
3. После того, как данные записаны, все поля на странице этом окне очищаются, а в главном окне на текущей странице обновляется ListView (добавляется новая запись).

Собственно, не могу реализовать момент, когда данные записываются в БД и чтобы после этого в главном окне на открытой странице обновлялся список.
В интернете нашел варианты реализации, но там везде без страниц сделано, а только окнами. Пробовал - не получилось.

Может быть есть какие-то похожие примеры? Или советы, как это сделать? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Возвращайте объект на добавление из модального окна и добавляйте в бд и на `ListView` непосредственно из главного окна. Либо можете пересмотреть архитектуру приложения и начать использовать `MVVM`.

Comment: @AGS17 спасибо. Можно чуть поподробнее по поводу возвращения объекта на добавления из модального окна? Метод, который добавляет данные в бд находится в классе всплывающего окна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как это **следует сделать**, если мы говорим о красивом решении с использованием `MVVM`:

- разделяете логику вьюх и вьюмоделей;
- абстрагируете бизнес логику для работы с базой в отдельный сервис;
- в этом сервисе создаете `event`'ы, которые будут оповещать о смене данных;
- при заходе на вьюху подписываетесь на необходимые события ваших сервисов;
- при выходи с вьюх, соответственно, отписываетесь.

Как это можно сделать сейчас на скорую руку:

1. переносите всю логику добавления данных в бд с модального окна на главное;
2. делаете `public get` свойство на модальном окне на тот объект, который вы раньше добавляли в базу;
3. после `.ShowDialog()` если завершилась нажатием `ok` (или чего там еще) добавляете в базу и в вашу `ListView` коллекцию.